# Authentication key isn't automatically imported when adding a PPA

Tags: 11.10, ppa

In previous Ubuntu releases adding a PPA in Software Sources imported an authentication key automatically. But since I installed 11.10 this feature is gone, so I must save and import the key manually. Is it a bug, or I can just change something in configs to get autoimport back?

Answer (score 3):

If you add the ppa from the command line it will automatically import the key for you.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/package
```

Comment: If it worked then please mark the question as answered